# systemctl issues: "transmission-daemon.service changed on disk" can't get rid of warning

Tags: systemd, services, transmission

I noticed whenever I restarted transmission-daemon on my machine I saw this:

```
 Warning: transmission-daemon.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

I run the command and check it with

```
 sudo systemctl status transmission-daemon
```

This is the result:

```
● transmission-daemon.service - Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service.d
           └─local.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-07-03 16:32:18 EDT; 13s ago
 Main PID: 662 (transmission-da)
   Status: "Uploading 2.73 KBps, Downloading 1.39 KBps."
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/transmission-daemon.service
           └─662 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error -g /etc/transmission-daemon
```

And the warning is gone. However, if I restart the machine the warning returns when I check the status again.

Why would the transmission-daemon.service file be changing?

When I run `ls -la` I get this back in the last modified date:

```
$ la /lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service                                                                        
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 284 Jan 12 02:00 /lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service
```

And Jan 12 was six months ago, so it appears it hasn't changed.

What can I do to get rid of the warning? (I'm troubleshooting some mysterious non-responsiveness and want to rule this out)

Am I asking the right questions? Is there something else I should be doing?

I'm running ARMBIAN 5.35 Stretch on a BananaPi Pro.

Thanks!

Comment: I notice `systemctl` is loading `/etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service.d/local.conf` in addition to `/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service`.  Anything interesting in that `local.conf` file?  Has that file registered any recent changes?

Comment: Hi @GracefulRestart

Gave it a look. `local.conf` was last modified on April 13.

It's contents are:

     `[Service]
     ExecStart=
     ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error -g /etc/transmission-daemon`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Nothing that I see in the output would cause the behavior you are describing.  I did  a quick search, and found [a systemd bug similar to what you describe](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3123) that looks like the fix would have been released with `systemd-230`.  If your systemd is older then that, that could be the issue.  If not, I am out of ideas.

Comment: Hmm... `systemd --v` gives me `systemd 232` Thanks for trying!

Comment: Do you have a systemd generator that may touch this file?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek not 100% sure. I looked under `/run/systemd/generator` and `/run/systemd/generator.late` and saw nothing with the name transmission in it. Anywhere else I should look or dig a bit deeper?

Comment: Nothing in `/etc/systemd/system-generators`? or same for `.../user-generators`. See also in `/usr/lib/systemd` and `/usr/local/lib/systemd`. You can also run `systemd-analyze` to see what has been done during boot, maybe it can give hints.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - thanks. I checked those directories and some didn't exist, those that did were empty or didn't list a transmission-daemon generator. I read the man page for `systemd-analyze` then ran `systemd-analyze --order dump` into a text file. `transmission-daemon.service` shows up, but no mention of a generator. `system-analyze blame` shows `transmission-daemon.service` in 2nd place at 46s. What do you think?